# Node.js Cheerio parser breaks UTF-8 encoding

Tags: node.js, encoding, cheerio

I parse my request with Cheerio like this:

```
var url = http://shop.nag.ru/catalog/16939.IP-videonablyudenie-OMNY/16944.IP-kamery-OMNY-c-vario-obektivom/16704.OMNY-1000-PRO;
request.get(url, function (err, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
   $ = cheerio.load(body);
   console.log($(".description").html());
});
```

And as output I see content but in unreadable strange encoding:

```
//Plain body console.log(body) (p.s. russian chars): 
<h1><span style="font-size: 16px;">Уличная 3Мп IP HD камера OMNY - попробуйте найти лучше</span></h1><p style

//  cheerio's console.log $(".description").html()
<h1><span style="font-size: 16px;">&#x423;&#x43B;&#x438;&#x447;&#x43D;&#x430;&#x44F; 3&#x41C;&#x43F; IP HD &#x43A;&#x430;&#x43C;&#x435;&#x440;&#x430; OMNY
```

Target url link coding is in UTF-8 format. So why Cheerio breaks my encoding?

Trying to use iconv to encode my body responce:

```
var body1 = iconv.decode(body, "utf-8");
```

but `console.log($(".description").html());` still returns weird text.

Comment: check this response in regards to dealing with the encoding
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805566/weird-characters-when-using-console-print-cheerio-nodejs

Comment: nope, still the same result:(

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Cheerio hasn't broken anything. It's outputting [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity), which will be rendered by any browser exactly the same as the HTML input. Run this snippet to see what I mean:

```html
<h1><span style="font-size: 16px;">Уличная 3Мп IP HD камера OMNY - попробуйте найти лучше</span></h1>

<h1><span style="font-size: 16px;">&#x423;&#x43B;&#x438;&#x447;&#x43D;&#x430;&#x44F; 3&#x41C;&#x43F; IP HD &#x43A;&#x430;&#x43C;&#x435;&#x440;&#x430; OMNY - &#x43F;&#x43E;&#x43F;&#x440;&#x43E;&#x431;&#x443;&#x439;&#x442;&#x435; &#x43D;&#x430;&#x439;&#x442;&#x438; &#x43B;&#x443;&#x447;&#x448;&#x435;</span></h1>
```

`&#x423;`, for example, is the character `У` encoded as an HTML entity, in the same way the entity `&gt;` represents `>`.

However, if you want to get the unencoded text, you can set the `decodeEntities` option to `false`:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(
  `<h1><span style="font-size: 16px;">Уличная 3Мп IP HD камера OMNY - попробуйте найти лучше</span></h1>`,
  { decodeEntities: false }
);


console.log($('span').html())
// => Уличная 3Мп IP HD камера OMNY - попробуйте найти лучше
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/cheerio@1.0.0-rc.3"></script>
```

Comment: This avoid also the firt &#xFEFF; char added in Cheerio output, thx.

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works for gulp-cheerio as well. I've just used this option like that: gulp.src("./mysrc")
        .pipe(cheerio({
            run: function ($, file) {
                // do something here...
            },
            parserOptions: {
                xmlMode: true,
                decodeEntities: false
            }
        }))

Answer (score 4):

I was having an issue early today when tried to load with cheerio a page where we had special characters like `ç`, `á`, `é`, etc...

The way cheerio works is that is tries to decode characters by nature and present the numerical HTML encoding of the Unicode character

**for example:** instead of `ç` it would give us `&#xE7;`.

In order to sort that issue, I just had to turn off this config by adding: `decodeEntities: false` as a cheerio load param.

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(body, { decodeEntities: false });
```