# node js cheerio get html text with formating tags

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I using cheerion to get html formate text, but when I get $("element").html(); the html return in hex:

```
&#x413;&#x430;&#x441;&#x442;&#x440;&#x43E;&#x43B;&#x438; &#x413;&#x43E;&#x441;&#x443;&#x434;&#x430;&#x440;&#x441;&#x442;&#x432;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x43D;&#x43E;&#x433;&#x43E; &#x410;&#x43A;&#x430;&#x434;&#x435;&#x43C;&#x438;&#x447;&#x435;&#x441;&#x43A;&#x43E;&#x433;&#x43E; &#x442;&#x435;&#x430;&#x442;&#x440;&#x430; &#x438;&#x43C;. &#x41C;&#x43E;&#x441;&#x441;&#x43E;&#x432;&#x435;&#x442;&#x430;<br><b><br>&#x412;&#x418;&#x428;&#x41D;&#x415;&#x412;&#x42B;&#x419; &#x421;&#x410;&#x414; - &#x410;.&#x41F;.&#x427;&#x415;&#x425;&#x41E;&#x412;<br><br><i>&#x41A;&#x43E;&#x43C;&#x435;&#x434;&#x438;&#x44F; &#x432; 4-&#x445; &#x434;&#x435;&#x439;&#x441;&#x442;&#x432;&#x438;&#x44F;&#x445;</i></b><br><br>&#x41F;&#x43E;&#x441;&#x442;&#x430;&#x43D;&#x43E;&#x432;&#x43A;&#x430; &#x438; &#x441;&#x446;&#x435;&#x43D;&#x43E;&#x433;&#x440;&#x430;&#x444;&#x438;&#x44F;
```

but I need to save all formate tags like `<br>,<i>,<b>` and text will be like this:

```
<i> <b> <br> NO AGE RESTRICTIONS !!! </ b> </ i> <br> <br> <b> The iconic figure of Russian show business Yegor Creed will soon present his new solo program to Israeli audiences </ b> <br> <br> At the moment, <b> Egor Creed </ b> is one of the most sought-after performers on the Russian stage, his tracks are in the first lines of radio station charts, and the clips are gaining millions of hits . <br> <br> The solo artist's program consists of hits and singles already known to all from the new album "What Do They Know?" The new record offers us to see an adult musician: the texts are more informative, the music is more interesting. The album sounds at the level of world music trends and sets a new benchmark for our show business. <br>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Cheerio parser breaks UTF-8 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574127/node-js-cheerio-parser-breaks-utf-8-encoding)

Comment: Take a look on [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31574528/5452965) SO answer. You need to pass `{decodeEntities: false}` when loading the HTML

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I need to format tags like: "<i> <b> <br> NO AGE RESTRICTIONS !!! </ b> </ i>" not only text, the text I can get using: $("element").text();

Comment: What does the input look like? Missing a [mcve] here.