# Node.js Cheerio parser breaks UTF-8 encoding of <link> hrefs

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I have a basic index.html file that I load with cheerio, modify the content of a tag, then rewrite the index.html.

My issue is that in that index.html, i have a  tag in which the href has a '&' symbol, that is interpreted by cheerio as a '&' on load of the file.
This leads to my index.html being rewritten with an incorrect href in this  tag.

original  :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

after being loaded by cheerio :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

I know that it is normal for cheerio to output special characters as HTML entities, and that it's not an issue in most cases, but here it modifies an URL and so breaks it.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31574127/node-js-cheerio-parser-breaks-utf-8-encoding/31574528#31574528) that it was possible to get undecoded text to bypass this issue by setting `decodeEntities: false` on loading but it simply does nothing.

```
const $ = cheerio.load(data, { decodeEntities: false });
```

Any clue on how to force cheerio to not transform special characters into HTML entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a version difference. It appears that the `decodeEntities` option is supported by the `htmlparser2` library that Cheerio uses in versions before 1.0, but not by the `parse5` library that is its default for HTML in recent versions.

To [use htmlparser2 for HTML](https://cheerio.js.org/docs/advanced/configuring-cheerio#using-htmlparser2-for-html), you can pass the `xml` option to have Cheerio select `htmlparser2` instead of `parse5`, but then tell `htmlparser2` that it shouldn't actually use its XML mode:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(data, { xml: { xmlMode: false, decodeEntities: false }});
```

If this solves the issue, you may want to add a comment with a link to the docs to explain what's going on here.

Comment: It works! I added the commentary to my code, thanks again :)