# Cheerio's text() returns � (U+FFFD) for some characters

Tags: node.js, json, web-scraping, character-encoding, cheerio

I'm creating a website scraping API, and sometimes there are special characters, often in names, eg. "Jesús M.Vargas".

My API downloads website content using `request` library and passes page's body to cheerio like this: `const body = cheerio.load(page);`

Then, I try to find text on the page, I know it's always the first `<b>`: `var copyright = body('b').eq(0).text().trim();`

Next, my code adds everything (like title, copyright, etc) to an object (`{}`) using pieces of code like `data["copyright"] = copyright;`

The last thing is to return the object to user as JSON object:

```
app.get("/api/", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  // query parameters
  const date = req.query.date;
  .
  . // get the webpage, find the data, add everything to an object
  .
  // get the data from `data` object and return it as JSON
  var output = JSON.stringify(data);
  res.send(output);
}
```

When the API returns text like in the example above, "Jes�s M.Vargas" is visible in the JSON file. Is there a way to fix these characters? For stringifying object I'm using vanilla JavaScript, my web framework is Express

Comment: *I'm getting "Jes�s M.Vargas"* - where are you getting it? Is there an evidence that the string really contains `U+FFFD` symbol, or you're judging from console output?

Comment: Sorry for imprecision, I'm getting this string in JSON output

Comment: Where is this output? In the console? Did you try to write it to file and how? This is encoding problem. There's a chance that the text is valid Unicode and the problem is where you use it. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that could help to understand at which point the problem appears.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my post

Comment: *"Jes�s M.Vargas" is visible in the JSON file* - where exactly is this visible? As I said, the problem may be in the place where you use the string. There's no evidence that text() returns incorrect string.

Comment: It's visible in "copyright" key/value pair

Comment: Visible **where**? Please, provide a screenshot.

Comment: Sure: https://i.imgur.com/ZK0JY5F.png

Comment: How did you output this file and how are you watching it? It's possible that you're viewing it with wrong encoding. I would suggest to assert that `copyright === 'Jesús M.Vargas'` and `copyright === 'Jes�s M.Vargas'` on *server side*, so you would know if you're sending correct data or not. The problem cannot be currently solved because you didn't provide enough information to solve it. As I said, there's no evidence that text() returns incorrect data. You need to eliminate possibilities one by one, nobody but you can't do this.

Comment: If anyone has a similar problem, I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805566/weird-characters-when-using-console-print-cheerio-nodejs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird characters when using console.print cheerio + nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805566/weird-characters-when-using-console-print-cheerio-nodejs)